# How do I configure CakePHP to run on WAMP without using bin\cake server or :8765?

Tags: apache, cakephp, cakephp-3.0

I'd like to run CakePHP on WAMP but without having to run `bin\cake server` or use the default port `:8765` but I am struggling to figure out how.

I tried changing apache httpd.conf to

```
DocumentRoot "c:/wamp/www/dev/cakephp3/tradeshows/webroot"
```

Which is what I took away from http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/installation.html#production

But it doesn't work still.

`http://localhost` does show the CakePHP landing page, but when I try going to `http://localhost/events` I'm getting:

> Not Found
>
> The requested URL /events was not found on this server.

If I go to `http://localhost:8765/events` and do `bin\cake server` then it works perfectly.

How can I make it so that I don't have to run `bin\cake server` to work correctly? I'm just trying to make a simple database for me and my coworker to use on our computers to put in tradeshow information.

Comment: Sounds like a possible `mod_rewrite` issue...

Comment: @ndm would that be http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/installation.html#apache ? I tried that in the /wamp/www/dev/cakephp3/tradeshows/.htaccess and it made it worse

Comment: @ndm got it, the link in my above comment worked after realizing it should have been done in the main wamp httpd.conf file

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Following the tutorial [here](http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/installation.html#apache) I was able to get it working, first time I tried I was editing the wrong config file:

Open `C:\wamp\bin\apache\apache2.4.9\httpd.conf`

Edit the part `<Directory />` to read:

```
<Directory />
    Options FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride All
#    Order deny,allow
#    Deny from all
</Directory>
```

Then also had to uncomment the line:

```
LoadModule rewrite_module modules/mod_rewrite.so
```

Which is different slightly than what's in the link but still did the job.